# Kendo NumericTextBox styling

Tags: telerik, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have the following  and I would like to know how I can get rid off the area in yellow.  Thanks for your help!

@Html.LabelFor(e => e.Invoice)

```
    @(Html.Kendo().NumericTextBoxFor(e => e.Invoice)
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 100%; border: 0px;" })
        .Format("#")
        .Decimals(0)
        .Spinners(false)
    )
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please specify what is the area in yellow??

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue by adding - display: inline-block -

Thanks all.